# pushing the new view controller (programatically) doesnt work ? why?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

[image]Here I am in a viewController and I want to go to another viewController with id of `ViewUSRControllerID` here is my code . The objective to move after I the user logged in :

```
@IBAction func login_btn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if username_txt.text == "" || password_txt.text == "" {

        //print("empty")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "you must fill up both username and password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else if (username_txt.text! == "admin" && password_txt.text! == "Passw0rd" ){

             print("login successful")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let cr = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewUSRControllerID")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cr, animated: true)


        }
    }
```

The output is that I can print the `login successful` but no pushing is being made . For the sake of testing I replaced :

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cr, animated: true)
```

with : 
self.present(cr, animated: true)

at it works fine . But why the pushing doesnt work ?

Comment: is your controller embeded with navigation controller?

Comment: I think it is , please refer to the question again . I've updated it .

Comment: my bad , I 've got it ;)

Comment: from which controller are you trying to push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code
`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cr, animated: true)`

`self.navigationController?` is optional property of `UIViewController` if your `LoginViewController` is embedded With `UINavigationController` than you can use `UINavigationController` method `pushViewController` and this method push `ViewUSRController` from `LoginViewController`.

So if you are using storyboard than it's very simple to embedded `UINavigationController` in `LoginViewController`.

Steps :-

1.Select `LoginViewController` in storyboard.
2.xCpode top panel "Editor"
3.Select "Embed in" -> `UINavigationController`

It's looks like this

[image]